# json deserialization with interface, spring java framework

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring

My front is in javascript and my backend in java (framework spring)

I have this java classes mapping:

```
Class Toto {
   ITata tata;
   String test;
}

public Interface ITata {
}

public class Tata1 implements ITata {
   String name;
}

public class Tata2 implements ITata {
   String age;
}
```

is it possible to parse json request?

I use java spring framework with annotations

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = 
RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JsonResponseBody doGetAudioArchiveRequest(@Valid @RequestBody Toto 
toto) {
...
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here??

Comment: Are you sure that the first word (Classe) is correctly written in your example?

Comment: i've got error: can not construct instance of ITata: abstract types either need to be maaped to concret types; have custom deserializer, or conatin additional type information.


Javascript side i post:

ajax: {
      "url": '/test',
      "type": "POST",
      data: function (data) { 
          var newData = Object();
          newData.tata= {};
          newData.tata.age = "20";
          return newData;
      },
      "dataSrc": function (returnedDataFromBackend) {
               ...
      }
}

Comment: perhaps, javascript side, i have to specify type of my interface to mapping tata1?

Comment: Spring tries to auto deserialize your JSON to the Toto class, but it cannot understand which type of ITata it should use for deserialisation. in this case you cannot use the automatic deserialasation but you have to write your own. Or you change your code to now use an interface for Tata1 and Tata2 but have them as two seperate variables within your Toto class

Comment: it cannot run with @JsonSubTypes?